# Pre-charge circuit for USB devices

Tags: capacitor, usb, charging

Mains SMPS converter chips (e.g. L6565) usually have pre-charge function to prevent the inrush current into a completely discharged capacitor. In high-power PSUs, a precharge resistor is often used, which is shunted by a relay once the SMPS starts providing output voltage.

What precharge circuit could be used for small low-power USB devices? For instance, I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek30K.jpg) DC-DC converter I power from USB, which has an input capacitance of 2x220uF (44 times the allowed limit of 10uF). Not surprisingly, when I connect it to a USB port, it produces overcurrent. With most USB hubs, this results in all the devices connected to the same hub to be re-connected.

Are there better options for a DIY-rework than a pre-charge resistor plus a small relay? How is this problem solved in properly designed USB devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a time-triggered switch using a MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fokCWt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The time constant responsible for switching the FET (R1xC1) is 10 times larger than the precharge time constant (R3xC2), so by the time M1 starts conducing, C2 is already charged to > 90% via R3.